# Using rank to select top 10 tuples in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the relation instructor(ID, name, dept name, salary).

The question in our assignment asks us to: Use the rank function in SQL to write a query to nd the id and name of those instructors in the top 10 most highly paid.

I'm able to rank the instructors through using `select id, name, rank() over(order by(salary) desc) as sal
from instructor order by sal`

What is my next step in grabbing the top 10 instructors? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Your [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335924/using-rank-to-select-top-10-tuples-in-oracle-sql/2335942#2335942) is close to the answer but it's generally better to use the value given by the RANK() function:

```
select id
       , name
       , sal
from (
  select id
        , name
        , sal
        , rank() over(order by(salary) desc) as sal_rank
    from instructor
  )
where sal_rank <=10
/
```

The problem with rownum is that it arbitrarily truncates the result set.  If we have a tie for tenth place it is usually important to know that fact.  Using ROWNUM returns a single random record instead.

Sometimes ROWNUM - or the analytic ROW_NUMBER() - will be correct.  It depends on the precise business requirements.

Answer (score -1):

I just figured it out actually, using rownum...

```
select id, name from(
  select id, name, rank() over(order by(salary) desc) as sal
    from instructor order by sal
  )
where rownum <=10
```

Hopefully this helps someone in the future!